# Some cities aren't instances of city or big city? Odd behaviour of Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

While examining the results of the official example query "Continents, countries, regions and capitals" (on https://query.wikidata.org/, limited to Germany for your convenience here: [link](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Continents%2C%20countries%2C%20regions%20and%20capitals%0A%23defaultView%3ATree%0ASELECT%20%3Fcontinent%20%3FcontinentFlag%20%3FcontinentLabel%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FcountryFlag%20%3Fregion%20%3FregionLabel%20%3FregionFlag%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3FcityImage%20%3Fproperty%20%3FpropertyLabel%20%3Fvalue%20%3FvalueLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%2A%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcontinent%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5107.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP30%20%3Fcontinent.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP150%20%3Fregion.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Fcountry%20%3D%20wd%3AQ183%29.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcontinent%20wdt%3AP242%20%3FcontinentFlag.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP41%20%3FcountryFlag.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fregion%20wdt%3AP41%20%3FregionFlag.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fregion%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcity.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ515.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP18%20%3FcityImage.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fprop%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP1082%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP6%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP190%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP31%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP571%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP150%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP206%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP527%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%3Fprop%20%3Fvalue.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fref%20%3Fprop.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20rdf%3Atype%20wikibase%3AProperty.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)), I noticed that some capitals of German federal states were missing. For example Wiesbaden as capital of Hesse. I noticed that Wiesbaden is an instance of `big city`, but not of `city` (see https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1721), in contrast to some other cities. I was able to alleviate the problem by also including cities that are subclasses of `city` by changing line 17 to `?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279? wd:Q515`.
One of the four cities that are still missing is Magdeburg, the capital of Saxony-Anhalt.
The diagnostic query

```sql
SELECT ?cityLabel ?props
WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P31 ?props.
  FILTER(?city = wd:Q1733 || ?city = wd:Q1726).
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

shows that Magdeburg is not even an instance of `city`, although it clearly is according to its Wikidata page https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1733.

I am new to Wikidata and SPARQL. However, this seems wrong to me. What can I do to get all capitals of the german federal states? And what is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you're doing anything wrong. The query `SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q1733 wdt:P31 ?o
}` should return all types, but it looks like something goes wrong.

Comment: Well, it looks like for statements with no references only one is returned. For example, the query to get the country `SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q1733 wdt:P17 ?o
}` also returns just one value. On the other hand, if you look at statements for `capital of` with `SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q1733 wdt:P1376 ?o
}` it returns multiple values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These missing statements are not [truthy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements):

```
SELECT ?statement ?valueLabel ?rank ?best
WHERE {
  wd:Q1733 p:P31 ?statement.
  ?statement ps:P31 ?value .
  ?statement wikibase:rank ?rank .
  OPTIONAL { ?statement a ?best . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fstatement%20%3FvalueLabel%20%3Frank%20%3Fbest%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ1733%20p%3AP31%20%3Fstatement.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP31%20%3Fvalue%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20wikibase%3Arank%20%3Frank%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20a%20%3Fbest%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

They are normal-rank statements, but there is a preferred-rank statement.

> Truthy statements represent statements that have the best
>   non-deprecated rank for given property. Namely, if there is a
>   preferred statement for property P2, then only preferred statements
>   for P2 will be considered truthy. Otherwise, all normal-rank
>   statements for P2 are considered truthy.

**Update**

I have [decreased](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Ranking#How_to_apply_ranks) the rank of the preferred statement [just now](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q1733&diff=prev&oldid=588379443). Please test your query again.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know this also holds for `instance of` statements. To be honest, I don't understand why those statements are not considered to be true. I mean, Munich a city?

Comment: @AKSW, I have updated my answer. In short, all non-deprecated statements are truthy, but preferred statements are even more truthy..

Comment: In fact, it was an act of (occasional) vandalism: https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q1733&diff=prev&oldid=572814192

Comment: +1, accepted, it works, thanks. Although I did not know about ranks, that was one theoretical possibility, I pondered. However, it does not make much sense in this case. The statement "Magdeburg is a city" should be true in a knowledge base. However, it is only true on the wikidata page, but not in the SPARQL query. Oh boy, this is a potential source for a lot of trouble.