# wikidata query missing out countries in Europe

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am using the following query against wikidata;

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel
      WHERE
      {
        ?country   wdt:P30 wd:Q46;
                   wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language
        "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
      }
```

where P30 is continent; Q46 is Europe; P31 is Instance Of and Q6256 is country;

https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%20wdt%3AP30%20wd%3AQ46%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D

Yet this query only returns 15 countries of Europe.  For instance Sweden is not returned even though Sweden appears to match the query at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q34

So even though the query seems to be correct yet it is missing out many countries.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

While comparing the two entries; one for Germany/Sweden (which do not show up) and Norway which does show up, the difference I could find was that Germany/Sweden has a preferred rank for Sovereign State while just a normal rank for Country.  This could be a reason where the WHERE clause decides to only show the preferred rank if it exists; and skip the remaining statements.  If this be the case and I suspect it is; I wonder if there is a way to override the behavior of the query engine to search through all statements with either a preferred rank or a normal rank.

Comment: `wdt:P31/wdt:P279*` would return much more results. Clearly, not all of them what you would expect to get

Comment: Not sure I understand what references has to do with it.  For instance Portugal has 0 references for instance of country; yet it shows up. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q45.  I feel it might be due to the preferred rank masking out the normal ranks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100906/7879193

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a better selection of countries when going around the truthy's by using statements. The statements are able to pull out all the statements even those with normal ranks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?countryLabel
      WHERE
      {
        ?country   wdt:P30 wd:Q46.
        ?country p:P31 ?country_instance_of_statement .
        ?country_instance_of_statement ps:P31 wd:Q6256 .
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language
        "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". 
        }
        filter not exists{?country p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q3024240 }
      } 
      order by ?countryLabel
```

I still have a few extra countries showing up; such as German Empire. But I think that's a different problem to fix.

https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fcountry_instance_of_statement%20%3FcountryLabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%20wdt%3AP30%20wd%3AQ46.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20p%3AP31%20%3Fcountry_instance_of_statement%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry_instance_of_statement%20ps%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%20not%20exists%7B%3Fcountry%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A

Note that country_instance_of_statement captures all the statements irrespective of rank. And once I have those than I use 'ps:P31 wd:Q6256' to pull out those that have country ("wd:Q6256") as the object.

I have added in suggestions from @AKSW above.

And for those who want another approach using end time for country, this is the sparql

```
SELECT distinct ?country ?countryLabel
      WHERE
      {
        ?country   wdt:P30 wd:Q46.
        ?country p:P31 ?country_instance_of_statement .
        ?country_instance_of_statement ps:P31 wd:Q6256 .
        filter not exists {?country_instance_of_statement pq:P582 ?endTime }
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language
        "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". 
        }
      } 
      order by ?countryLabel
```

https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fcountry_instance_of_statement%20%3FcountryLabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20%20wdt%3AP30%20wd%3AQ46.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20p%3AP31%20%3Fcountry_instance_of_statement%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry_instance_of_statement%20ps%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%3Fcountry_instance_of_statement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FendTime%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A

Comment: yeah, sometimes it's really weird with the data. You could use a filter to ignore historical countries with `filter not exists{?country p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q3024240 }`. You should also do `SELECT distinct ?country ?countryLabel` because for Switzerland there are two statements. So in the end, we get 51 countries which is correct.

Comment: @AKSW - Thanks, I was thinking of testing to see if there is no "end time" in country, but this would do as well.  I have made the changes but I still have 52 countries with Kingdom of the Netherlands showing up in addition to Netherlands.

Comment: your query does also return Switzerland twice because of two bindings for `?country_instance_of_statement` variable. Once you remove it and use `DISTINCT` it works.

Comment: Regarding Netherlands, yeah - weird. But *Netherlands* is just the country in Europe while *Kingdom of the Netherlands* does also include its colonies in the Caribbean Sea

Comment: Well, I double checked the result. What I can say, Austria is missing here. Not sure why but it's not an instance of country. Maybe state or sovereign state is more appropriate?

Comment: `SELECT distinct ?country  ?countryLabel
      WHERE
      {
        ?country   wdt:P30 wd:Q46.
        ?country p:P31 ?country_instance_of_statement .
        ?country_instance_of_statement ps:P31 wd:Q3624078
        
        filter not exists{?country p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q3024240 }
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language
        "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". 
        }
      } 
order by ?countryLabel`

Comment: I am going to leave it be by country (not sovereign state) else it might cause issues in other continents.  Austria should be fixed in wikidata to have a country property. @AKSW - per your suggestion, I have removed the additional binding for ?country_instance_of_statement and put in an ORDER BY.