# SPARQL wikidata returns less countries instead of all

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to list out all the countries. I tried this below query. It returns **166** results. But, I think total of more than 190, 200 countries are in the world. But, why it returns only 166 country names?

Am I doing anything wrong here? This is silly question for some people, but I am new to SPARQL & wikidata

**[Wikidata Query](https://w.wiki/763)**

```
# list all countries

SELECT ?country ?countryLabel
WHERE
{
    ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 .

    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ASC(?countryLabel)
```

Comment: do you know which counties are missing?

Comment: @Alexan Ukraine, Serbia, Suriname, Russia

Comment: truthy vs non-truthy data

Comment: @AKSW Can you explain more about that?

Comment: `# list all countries

SELECT ?country ?countryLabel
WHERE
{
    ?country p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q6256 .
  
  
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ASC(?countryLabel)`

Comment: for countries like Russia, wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 is not the preferred rank, but a different type. You can have a look at the slides: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Wikidata%27s_SPARQL_introduction_presentation.pdf

Comment: @AKSW Can you explain this `ps:P31`. 

Post your comment as an answer. I will accept it as right answer.

Comment: @AKSW Can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

As @AKSW has noted, the query that correctly returns all countries is:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel
WHERE
{
    ?country p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q6256 .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ASC(?countryLabel)
```

The only difference from your query is the line `?country p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q6256 .`

The slash (`/`) in that line is a shorthand notation. The line can be expanded as:

```
?country p:P31 ?statement .
?statement ps:P31 wd:Q6256 .
```

- The 1st line means "entities that are the subject of statements"
- The 2nd line means "which state that something is a country"

The prefixes `p:` and `ps:` are namespaces. Wikidata's convention is to keep entity-to-statement connectors in the `p` namespace and statement-to-value connectors in the `ps` namespace. They must be linked together to query for the list of countries.

This may seem like a lot of complexity. You just want to find countries; you don't care about statements *about* countries. Thus, the `wdt:` prefix was created for use cases like yours. This namespace is supposed to summarize `p:/ps:` linkages for these simple yes-or-no queries.

But there's a problem! To quote from [the Wikidata SPARQL docs](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#US_presidents_and_their_spouses):

> Such triples, using the `wdt:` representation of the property, are not created for all statements, but for only statements that have the highest rank for the property on that item and are not deprecated. While not being guaranteed to be true, they are intended to summarise Wikidata's best current understanding of the truth.

In short, the `wdt:` namespace is incomplete and you found some of the holes. For whatever reason, a handful of countries like Suriname and Russia got left out of the statements in that namespace.

EDIT: This seems to [have something to do with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986633/sparql-query-does-not-yield-expected-results) being assigned as a "country" or as a "sovereign state". Using `Q3624078`, the sovereign state identifier, instead of `Q6256` also fixes your query.