# Differences between query.wikidata.org and wikidata.org

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I'm quite confused. Trying to get a list of Canadian provinces and territories, i.e. the first-level provinces. So I'm looking for a subclass of [Q10864048](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10864048) (first-level administrative country subdivision), related to Q16 (Canada). The subclass I'm looking for is of course [Q11828004](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11828004) (province of Canada), which is indeed a subclass of [Q10864048](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10864048).

So, [let's query the subclasses of Q10864048](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FregionClass%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3FregionClass%20wdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ10864048.%0A%7D). This does not yield Q11828004.

Strange. Wikidata says that Q11828004 is a subclass of Q10864048, but [query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org) says it is not. At least, query.wikidata.org finds 264 other direct subclasses of Q10864048.

Checking the SQID tool: https://sqid.toolforge.org/#/view?id=Q11828004. Yes, Q11828004 is a subclass of Q10864048.

Checking the superclass: https://sqid.toolforge.org/#/view?id=Q10864048. "Direct subclasses: none". So the SQID says that Q11828004 is a direct subclass of Q10864048, but Q10864048 has no subclasses?

And, how can a class have 14 total subclasses, when it does not have any *direct* subclass?

This does not make sense. Three tools, all saying something different, the SQID tool even contradicting itself.

One possibility would be that the tools are operating on different versions, i.e. a different data dump. However, the claim `Q11828004 P279 Q10864048` has been in the data since April 2017, so it should be present in all data dumps.

**What am I missing?**

Note: It seems that [query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org) knows about the relation `Q11828004 P279 Q2879`, and `Q2879 P279 Q10864048`. But this still does not explain the differences mentioned above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some cities aren't instances of city or big city? Odd behaviour of Wikidata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100068/some-cities-arent-instances-of-city-or-big-city-odd-behaviour-of-wikidata). See https://w.wiki/fXB.

Comment: @StanislavKralin this answers my main question. Thanks. Maybe it is also the answer for the contradiction in the SQID tool.

Comment: These things do get confusing... Check out the talk pages, such as https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata_talk:WikiProject_Country_subdivision#A_3_layer_model_to_class_subdivisions_and_their_type_with_instance_of_(P31)_and_subclass_of_(P279). Or try asking in https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Project_chat.