# `wd:Q887 wdt:P31 ?x` does not list that Yekaterinburg is a "big city". Why?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

[On the entity page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q887) it's listed that it's a "city or town" as well as "big city".

And if I query "What is Yekaterinburg?" via statement and specification I see that among other things it's "big city".

[Query](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%3Fx%20%3Fn%20where%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ887%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%20%3Fx.%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%3Fx%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fn.%20filter%28lang%28%3Fn%29%3D%27en%27%29.%7D%0A%7D%20limit%201000%0A%23%20%0A%23%20select%20%3Fx%20%3Fn%20where%20%7B%0A%23%20%20%20wd%3AQ887%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fx.%0A%23%20%20%20optional%20%7B%3Fx%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fn.%20filter%28lang%28%3Fn%29%3D%27en%27%29.%7D%0A%23%20%7D%20limit%201000%0A):

```
 select ?x ?n where {
   wd:Q887 p:P31 [ps:P31 ?x].
   optional {?x rdfs:label ?n. filter(lang(?n)='en').}
 } limit 1000
```

However if I query it via `wdt` I only see that it's "city or town" and not "big city".
Query:

```
 select ?x ?n where {
   wd:Q887 wdt:P31 ?x.
   optional {?x rdfs:label ?n. filter(lang(?n)='en').}
 } limit 1000
```

Why is that?

I could not find the explicit definition, but I thought that `wdt` is equivalent to sequence of `p/ps` turns out it's not.

Should `Q887` be edited to make `wdt:P31` refer to Yekatrinburg as a big city? If so, then how?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100906

Comment: in addition, you can read https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements