Cannot find Q60 New York City with a Wikidata query
The following query:
SELECT ?item WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q515 . FILTER(?item = wd:Q62) } LIMIT 10 
outputs Q62 (San Francisco) as expected but this query
SELECT ?item WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q515 . FILTER(?item = wd:Q60) } LIMIT 10  outputs nothing given that at the time of writing Q60 New York City is also an instance of a Q515 city.
I expected that both Q60 and Q62 behave the same.

New York's preferred-rank value for wdt:P31 is 'city in the United States'. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100906/7879193

Do not use FILTER for binding variables to specific values, but BIND (for single values) or VALUES (for many possible values).
